# glmer with gamma distribution - problem fitting model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, residuals, gamma-distribution

I am trying to fit the gamma distribution to my data as the residuals are not normally distributed but it has been much more difficult than I anticipated. The dependent variable is response times and the predictors are all categorical.
The linear model:

[image]

First, when I try to model it, it always shows convergence issues that I am not sure how to fix without scaling the variable which leads to negative values and the following warning:

```
Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family
```

The model :

```
glmer <- glmer(RT ~ V1*V2*V3 + (1|Participant), data= Data, family = Gamma(link = "log"),                      
control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

Throws this warning but like I said before, I am not sure how to rescale a gamma distribution.

```
  Warning messages:
  1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
     Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00889002 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
  2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
     Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
   - Rescale variables?
```

When I use this code to check the assumptions, it looks really weird. I have read that this may not be appropriate for mixed models.

```
   simulationOutput <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = glmer, use.u = T)
```

[image]

I then used this code to check the residuals:

```
  residuals <- residuals(glmer, type = "response", retype="normalized")
  plot(residuals)
```

[image]

How can I solve these issues or does this mean the gamma distribution is not a good fit for my data?

Comment: Please explain your study design and how the data arise. Also please include the plots for the linear model.

Comment: I posted some plots of the linear model here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482141/absence-of-normality-of-residuals-lmer-or-glmer/482226#482226

Comment: It looks like those plots are for a log model AND I don't see much description of the study design and how the data were measured

Comment: Sorry, just added the information to this post for the linear model. This is a simple response time task with one of the variables representing two types of trials in the task congruent or incongruent, block which is the within session time dimension and the final one - session because participants were tested twice, this is a repeated measures study.

Comment: You don't seem to want provide much information ? How many participants ? What is your research question(s) ? So V1 is trial type (2 levels), V2 is block (how many levels ?) and V3 is session number (1 or 2). Are you specifically interested in the effect of time (session number ?)

Comment: Also the model in the other question has 4 fixed efffects, but the one here has 3 !

Comment: The other model was another study but using the same task, just had an extra variable - as there were two groups. I thought it was the same thing, but ignore it please.
47 participants, 1000 trials each, though on average only 800 were included in the analysis (outlier removal and only correct responses were included). Block is a 5 level variable, we compare it consecutively - 1vs2, 2vs3, 3vs4, 4vs5. I am interested in determining whether there is an effect of type of trial; and whether this effect increases with time spent on the task, i.e. trial type * block and trial type * block * session

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111703/discussion-between-robert-long-and-catm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem here is:

> Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-positive values not allowed for the 'gamma' family

This is because you scaled the response variable to be centred around zero and the gamma model is only for positive values.

The other issues, that were fleshed out in the comments/chat is that `glmer` was having problems converging due to the way it approximates the integrals over the random effects in the definition of the marginal likelihood. The package `GLMMAdaptive` uses adaptive gauss hermite quadrature and was able to solve this problem with the log-transformed response. However this results in a model that is much harder to interpet than the linear model, while providing almost the same inferences and answers to the research questions.

Having said all that, the root issue in the question is that the gamma model fitted clearly has very poor fit to the data. The recommendation is to explore a model fitted on log response times since all response times are greater than 1, this should not be a problem, although there may be difficulties with interpretation.